# Location of Objects - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, oop, memory-management

When I executed the following code, i got value A.  When I executed it again, I got value B.  Why is that. Shouldn't it have produced the same result?

**Code**

```
list_a = ['one_A', 'two_A', 'three_A']

#initialize the list
new_li = map(lambda i: '{0}\n'.format(i), list_a)

print(new_li)
```

**Value A**

```
<map object at 0x00000000093E7E80>
```

**Value B**

```
<map object at 0x0000000009423080>
```

***Note***

I'm not asking how to turn a map object into a list. But rather why memory locations are different when the map object new_li is re-created.

Comment: Why would they be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, when you assign a variable to a value, it stores the value in a memory location, and then creates a reference to that object. As a result, your variable is just a reference.  So, if you assign a new value to the variable, it does not overwrite that memory location with the new value, but rather creates a new object in a new memory location and a new reference to that memory location.

See below for an example. In this case, the list [1,2] is stored in memory location 46777352 when a is created. When b is created, it is stored in memory location 46797512. Even though they have the same value, a is not b because they do not refer to the same memory location.  When a is re-assigned the value of [1,2,3], it does not change the value in memory location 46777352, but rather creates a new object in memory location 46812296.  Variable b retains a’s original memory location even though it was created after variable a.

**Example**

[image: Example]

**Further Reading**

Here are some good videos from pycon 2015 and 2016 which explain the concept.

*Facts and Myths about Python – Pycon 2015*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns&feature=youtu.be

*Python by Immersion – Pycon 2016*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9k5687mmnoc